# Can you help me figure out why my arduino code is not working

Tags: arduino-uno

The code is made to sense were an object is and send out

```
int const trigPin = 10;
int const echoPin = 9;
int const buzzPin = 1;
int const LED1 = 2;
int const LED2 = 3;
int const LED3 = 4;
void setup()
{
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); 
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); 
pinMode(buzzPin, OUTPUT); 
pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
int duration, distance;
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delay(1);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
//                                      Go
distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;
if (distance <= 1000 && distance >=0) { 
digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
} else {
digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
}
delay(60);
}
//                                      SLOW
if (distance <= 50 && distance >=0) { 
digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
} else {
digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
}
delay(60);
}
//                                      STOP
if (distance <= 50 && distance >=0) { 
digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
} else {
digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
}
delay(60);
}
```

Comment: `and send out` ... send out what to where?

Comment: to an LED and or Buzzer sorry I did right it in but for some reason it was cut off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding in some serial output at important code-parts. If you see that these are getting printed you can be sure that the code gets executed until that point. If it doesn't get executed it could also be a problem with the wiring so be sure to check that everythign is set up properly.

At this part:

```
...
void loop()
{
int duration, distance;
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delay(1);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
//                                      Go
distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;
...
```

You are trying to divide an integer (wich can only hold whole numbers) with a real number. Please make sure to use a data type wich can hold more fine-grained results like double or float.

To set up a serial interface you have to add **Serial.begin(9600)** to you code in the setup() function. Then when you write **Serial.println("Your debugging message here")** it should be visible in the serial monitor after compiling. (Arduino IDE->Tools->Serial Monitor)

Comment: It's not so easy to debug code if you can't compile it at all. Maybe, at some point, he finds out why is everyone using code indentation (and sometimes even [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md))

Comment: I just wanting to know but what would a debugging message be or look like because I am sort of new to Arduino and don't now about too much.

Comment: You just write as message whatever helps you. You could for example write as message:
Serial Port Started;
Sensor triggered;
Entering while loop.

It's really just up to you. Whatever helps you figuring out where your arduino is moving arround in your code right now